# FontAwesome code doesn't included in webpack css bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, font-awesome

I am using Webpack 5 and FontAwesome 5. I'm using `MiniCssExtractPlugin` to extract a bundle css file from SASS. The icons are shown normally, but when I inspect the page, there is a big style tag with a bunch of Fontawesome code and I don't want style tags in my page: [Devtools Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpWl1.png).

I've never used webpack, I'm still learning. I've researched and tried a lot of things, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**main.js (entry point)**

```js
// Importing SCSS
import "./scss/style.scss";

// Importing Fontawesome Icons
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/regular'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands'

//...
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    portal: "./src/portal/main.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "static/js/[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: '/dist/' 
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          },
        }       
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'static/fonts/[name][ext]',
        }
      },
      {
        // extract images (except svg)
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'static/img/[name][ext]',
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            //extract css into separate file
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            // translates CSS into CommonJS modules
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
          {
            // Run postcss actions
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              // `postcssOptions` is needed for postcss 8.x;
              // if you use postcss 7.x skip the key
              postcssOptions: {
                // postcss plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
                plugins: [
                  [
                    "autoprefixer",
                    {},
                  ],
                ],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            // compiles Sass to CSS
            loader: "sass-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "templates/[name][ext]",
        },
      },
 
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "static/css/[name].bundle.css"
    }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Font Awesome 5 to not inject CSS by setting the `config.autoAddCss` setting to `false` before using importing any Font Awesome icons, then importing the CSS manually. For example, in your case:

```js
// Importing SCSS
import "./scss/style.scss";

// Disable Font Awesome CSS
import { config } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
config.autoAddCss = false;

// Import Font Awesome CSS
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";

// Importing Fontawesome Icons
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/regular'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands'
```

You can find more information in Font Awesome's documentation under [Content Security Policy](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/dig-deeper/security#content-security-policy) (that sounds like a weird place for it, but you need to use that workaround to set the CSP correctly in some cases).